# Time between Viva (minor corrections) and the letter

Tags: phd, thesis, defense

I have been awarded a PhD today with minor corrections (yay!). I am not very relieved yet, because I signed a job contract that says that the deadline to provide a proof of a PhD award is September. I tried to search for the answer in the research regulations of my university but it was not there. I also asked my supervisor and she told me we're going to try to do that. Do you know roughly how long does it take usually to receive the letter after the viva in the UK? (minor correction that need to be sent to my supervisor).

Comment: In the U.S. you would contact the office of the registrar about this. At my university it took approximately 1-2 weeks after the final copy was turned into the graduate school. Some employers will also accept a letter from your department, which can have a much shorter turnaround.

Comment: It will probably depend on when the next meeting of the examinations board (or local equivalent) takes place, which is when such things are usually confirmed. Your university should have some regulations that you can consult—I would write to the examinations office and ask them.

Comment: If it's up to minor corrections that need to be approved by your supervisor, have him write you a letter (after approving your thesis) that your thesis is approved and it's only a matter of waiting for the formal letter. It works fine in the Netherlands where there is a long time between approval of a thesis through the examination committee and defense with official proof of PhD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of getting the official papers for a Ph.D. degree can last for months following the oral examination, depending on the university's policies and procedures.

That said, most universities are aware of the need for Ph.D. recipients to start jobs before the "official" Ph.D. degree is sent out, and there's usually a mechanism in place to issue a document stating that the oral examination has been passed and that the candidate is done except for the formal procedures required. Such paperwork is usually provided at an administrative level higher than the professor advising the Ph.D. candidate. You should consult with the graduate advisor of your department for guidance on who to contact.